# Using Faker Gem to Seed Data

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm attempting to seed my database using the `Faker` gem, but am getting some error messages and can't see where I'm going wrong.  My `seeds.rb` is:

```
10.times do
  List.create! (
    name: Faker::Company.buzzword,
    shared_with: Faker::Internet.email,
    user_id: 3
  )
end

50.times do
  Item.create! (
    name: Faker::Company.bs,
    list_id: Faker::Number.between(1, 10),
    delegated_to: Faker::Internet.email,
    user_id: 3
  )
end

puts "Seed finished"
puts "#{List.count} lists created"
puts "#{Item.count} items created"
```

And the error messages are:

```
rake aborted!
SyntaxError: /Users/.../db/seeds.rb:3: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
    name: Faker::Company.buzzword,
         ^
/Users/.../db/seeds.rb:4: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
    shared_with: Faker::Internet.email,
                ^
/Users/.../db/seeds.rb:5: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
    user_id: 3
            ^
/Users/.../db/seeds.rb:11: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL
    name: Faker::Company.bs,
         ^
/Users/.../db/seeds.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
    list_id: Faker::Number.between(1, 10),
            ^
/Users/.../db/seeds.rb:12: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting keyword_end
/Users/.../db/seeds.rb:14: syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
    user_id: 3
            ^
/Users/.../db/seeds.rb:20: syntax error, unexpected end-of-input, expecting keyword_end
```

Can anyone clue me in to where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Ruby you should never put whitespace between a method name and the opening parenthesis.

```
# Syntax error
List.create! (

# Correct
List.create!(
```

So to expand, your code should look like:

```
10.times do
  List.create!(
    name: Faker::Company.buzzword,
    shared_with: Faker::Internet.email,
    user_id: 3
  )
end
```

Comment: Goodness all that for a space!  I think that helped, but I'm now getting `NameError: uninitialized constant Faker`....

Comment: You need to add `require "faker"` to the top of your seeds.rb. If that doesn't work, make sure to put `gem "faker"` in your Gemfile and run `bundle install`.

Comment: I added `require "faker" to the top of my seeds file, and I previously installed faker with `gem install faker` as recommended on the faker github. Still getting `rake aborted!
LoadError: cannot load such file -- faker`

Comment: Ah, but it wasn't in my gemfile. Mission accomplished.  Thank you!